# jQuery .closest() method returning undefined on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

The jQuery method [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) is not working on iOS devices. I'm using `.closest()` with `event.target` to detect if the tapped target element has a specific ancestor. Unfortunately this returns and error on iOS devices.

---

**HTML**

```
<ul class="level-1">
    <li><a href="#" class="item-1">Level 1 - Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="item-2">Level 1 - Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="item-3">Level 1 - Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.item-1').on('touchstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.closest('.level-1'));
});
```

**Error**

[image]

---

Live example can be found at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7vn9gw5/1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the dom element's [closest method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)(`e.target` is a dom element reference) which is a experimental feature(supported by only a [few browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Browser_compatibility)), need to call jQuery [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest) method for cross browser compatibility

```
console.log($(e.target).closest('.level-1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "$(this)" to find the closest element.It basically returns a jquery object to call jquery's closest function

```
$('.item-1').on('touchstart', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).closest('.level-1'));
});
```